# mount command on Alpine Linux doesn't like octal sequence for space in fstab

Tags: networking, fstab, automounting, alpine-linux

on alpine Linux, I can't mount automatically a cifs directory which has a space in the name, but manually it may work.

With this /etc/fstab snippet it doesn't work:

```
//192.168.245.1/My\040Space              /media/myspace cifs rw,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

Although it works fine on a Debian machine!

On Alpine, this manual command doesn't work and ends with *failed: Invalid argument*:

```
mount -v -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials //192.168.245.1/My\040Space /media/myspace
```

This one **does** works:

```
mount -v -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials //192.168.245.1/"My Space" /media/myspace
```

Interestingly, in this successful case the /proc/mounts file contains the \040 escape sequence:

```
//192.168.245.1/My\040Space /media/myspace cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict ...
```

It looks like *mount* can't interpret octal escapes in fstab files nor in command line.

Any idea on how I can have it work?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, the `fstab` man page on my Debian says under the description of the second field that `\040` is supported to escape a space, but it seems to work here in the first field too, at least for a regular filesystem path. I wonder if that's supported at all on Alpine, or if it's just an issue with the CIFS mount. You could try  to mount another share to a path with a space to see if that works.

Comment: also no, `My\040Space` won't work in the shell, it's the same as `My040Space`. You'd need `$'My\040Space'` to have the escape interpreted

Comment: @ikkachu

Right: $'My\040Space' works. Thanks for pointing it.

So the issue is limited to escaping space in fstab, with Alpine (mount command, or CIFS)